MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error when trying to add a video to a playlist in MongoDB
I'm working on a MERN stack application where I have a Playlist document in MongoDB that looks like this:
{
  _id: new ObjectId('663296c9ca082f17ba715a4c'),
  name: 'My Fav 02',
  videos: [ new ObjectId('6631c108d41dfb12d6d076cd') ],
  userId: new ObjectId('6631bd463f5fe83acfb4913c'),
  __v: 0
}

I'm trying to add a video with an ObjectId of '6631bd613f5fe83acfb49141' to the videos array in the Playlist document. However, I'm encountering a MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error. The error message suggests that there's already a video with the same ObjectId in the videos array. But as per my document, only ObjectId of '6631c108d41dfb12d6d076cd' is present.
Here's the error message:
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: 64f7351729e1ad75103e28fa_test.playlists index: videos_1 dup key: { videos: ObjectId('6631bd613f5fe83acfb49141') }

And here's my API to add a video to a playlist:
router.put('/playlist/:id', authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const playlist = await Playlist.findById(req.params.id);
        if (playlist.userId.toString() !== req.body.userId) {
            return res.status(403).json({ message: 'Forbidden' });
        }
        console.log("videoId: ", req.body.videoId);
        // videoId:  6631bd613f5fe83acfb49141 (in console)
        playlist.videos.push(req.body.videoId);
        await playlist.save();
        res.json({ message: 'Video added to playlist' });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
});

I'm not sure why I'm getting a duplicate key error when the ObjectId I'm trying to add doesn't exist in the videos array. Any help would be appreciated.

Was videos an object in your schema before with an index then you changed the schema so that videos was now an array?

It seems the mongoose schema and the respective MongoDB collection are out of sync with respect to indexes. Let us reconcile it. Please go to a Mongo Shell instance, switch to your db, and then execute the statement db..getIndexes(), if you find any indexes listed and you are sure not relevant, please remove them and run the app again.

@jQueeny No, this pertains to the current instance. There's a distinct MongoDB schema for it, which is where I stored this data.

@WedothebestforYou, I attempted to implement your suggestion, which is to clear the database in Mongo, but the issue still persists.

Did you note the collection name in the error message ? it is  64f7351729e1ad75103e28fa_test.playlists. It is in the form dbName.collectionName. It means your current DB is 64f7351729e1ad75103e28fa_test and the collection is playlist. Is that something you are fully aware of? Second thing is : can you briefly update how did you try to clear the database as per your last action. Third thing is if the database side is correct, then please check if the values are correct. Please hard code and push as this to debug - playlist.videos.push('6631bd613f5fe83acfb49141');

@WedothebestforYou, 1. Yes, the current database is '64f7351729e1ad75103e28fa_test', and the collection name is 'playlist'. I have verified it. 2. I have directly deleted the database in the MongoDB Atlas Dashboard. 3. The issue in the post has been updated, taking into account your feedback, and I have verified that the video ID I am attempting to insert is indeed correct.

Thank you for your actions and the feedback. Please review the error message again -"...duplicate key error...key: { videos: ObjectId('6631bd613f5fe83acfb49141') }". It shows that the index is a "single key unique index". It means to the app as - the app will not allow to refer a particular video multiple times. Is it ok? What if another user wants to include the same video into his/her play list? What if the same user wants to create another playlist including the same video? ...

...Please review the nature of the index under such scenarios. It seems as the index should be a "unique composite one". It can be either on UserId and Videos or UserId, Videos and Play list name. Or It can be simply be a "duplicate one" just on Videos, but that requires a code for validation that the same Video has not been duplicated in the same playlist.
